# is whitepace two bytes in a file(read from C) in linux

Tags: c

I'm reading a file from C code. It looks the whitespace character is two bytes long. Is it so?

The contents of that file looks like below. I open that in binary mode.

```
11 22 43 34
```

Comment: What makes you think that the whitespace is two bytes?

Comment: In general whitespace characters are a single byte.  In some OS's (Windows), a "\n" in a C string does become two bytes in the file.  I believe it becomes "\n\r", or I might have it backwards.

Comment: @Jim Clay: Probably backwards, it's usually `\r\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that a space character can be 2 bytes if its Unicode(0x0020).

However, most text in still in ASCII or something that is backwards compatible with ASCII, which would make whitespace a single character on Linux machines.  On Windows, you could get a `\r\n` combination as Jim Clay mentioned.

Comment: The Unicode space character U+0020 is only two bytes if you're using a two-byte Unicode encoding such as UCS-2 (and in that case, *all* your characters are two bytes). In UTF-8 encoding, a space is still one byte.

Comment: In UTF-8 the plain space is one byte. Most (all?) other spaces are 3 bytes. :-)